# Using sum() to mimic count() of rows

Tags: mysql

I want to count the number of rows where a particular field = 'Q1'.

I usually use count(particular_field), but this does not allow me to count only when that field = 'Q1'.

Does the query `SUM(particular_field = 'Q1')` work for this matter? Or am I able to do `count(particular_field = 'Q1')`?

Comment: Why don't you try and see what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can either do

```
select count(*)
from table
where particular_field = 'Q1'
```

or

```
select sum(case when particular_field ='Q1' then 1 else 0 end)
from table
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a `CASE` statement with your `SUM()` (See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48eec/2))

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN particular_field = 'Q1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) yourCount
FROM yourTable
```

Or (See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48eec/3)) - this will give you a list of the count and each field. If you only want the one value, then use a `WHERE` clause to filter:

```
select count(*), particular_field 
from yourTable
group by particular_field
```